# Split long sentences in multiple lines with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a long sentences in my mysql fields and in my jquery table text appears like this:

```
In the aftermath of her sudden Vancouver celebrity, she appeared as the cover girl on Playboy magazine's October 1989 issue. At that point she decided to live in Los Angeles to further pursue her modeling career. Playboy subsequently chose her as Playmate of the Month in their February 1990 issue, in which she appeared in the centerfold photo.
```

[image: exceeds limit]

I want splitting long sentences in multiple lines after 12 words (example)

```
In the aftermath of her sudden Vancouver celebrity, she appeared as the
cover girl on Playboy magazine's October 1989 issue. At that point she 
decided to live in Los Angeles to further pursue her modeling career. Playboy 
subsequently chose her as Playmate of the Month in their February 1990
issue, in which she appeared in the centerfold photo.
```

What javascript code can I use?

Comment: You could split it into an array of words and then build lines of 12 words each from that. But I'd first try to make the web browser render it properly as it is, browsers are quite good at text layout.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is my code using javascript please check the demo. let me know if you have issues. I split by 12

```js
var paragraph = "In the aftermath of her sudden Vancouver celebrity, she appeared as the cover girl on Playboy magazine's October 1989 issue. At that point she decided to live in Los Angeles to further pursue her modeling career. Playboy subsequently chose her as Playmate of the Month in their February 1990 issue, in which she appeared in the centerfold photo. Heloo Im van testing this code";

$(function(){
var data = paragraph.split(' ');
  var x=0,y=0,iterator=12;
    var xarray =  data.length;
    for(var i = iterator;i < xarray; i +=iterator){
      $('#container').append(paragraph.split(/\s+/).slice(x,i).join(" ")+"<br />");
      y = xarray-i;  
      x = i;
        if(y<iterator){
         $('#container').append(paragraph.split(/\s+/).slice(x,i+y).join(" ")+"<br />");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is work on html pages but I have long sentences on mysql fields (long description) and I display results on a jquery-flexigrid table. In your case long sentences is written inside`var paragraph = " ....` including in html/php pages but I can't write javascript on mysql fields because i have not a javascript code that decode that. I use Autolinker.min.js for decoding html code writing inside mysql fields. Have you got a similar solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would add `word-wrap: break-word` to the cells and `table-layout: fixed` to the table, then you can specify a width for that column and text will wrap to multiple lines.

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

EDIT

if you give the cell a width, the contents will automatically wrap to multiple lines. You could either give the cell a class, or target it with `nth-child`

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5L87xj/)

Comment: I try to add this table code `<table style='border:1px solid black'><tr><td>TEXT</td></tr></table>` but text don't break. Can you post a correct table example with your CSS, please?

Comment: It works on html pages but is not possible include it in mysql fields and display correctly in flexigrid table. I insert your html and css code in mysql fields and decode it with Autolinker.min.js to display html correctly but see the result: http://i.imgur.com/CLEithW.png Seems that jquery resizable column feature of flexigrid table are not seen as delimiters. I use this http://sanderkorvemaker.nl/test/flexigrid/ table to display but I can t integrate your table.